# How to efficiently paginate through Youtube JSON response?

Tags: python, json, loops, youtube, youtube-api

I'm collecting info about videos from a Youtube channel, where the number of videos is > 50.

So it means that I need to make several requests, because the max result per JSON response is 50 videos.

I've found some solutions and now the code looks like this

```py
videoMetadata = [] #declaring our list, where the results will be stored

# First request
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId='+CHANNEL_ID+'&maxResults=50&type=video&key='+API_KEY

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url) #makes the call to YouTube

videos = json.load(response) #decodes the response so we can work with it

nextPageToken = videos.get("nextPageToken") #gets the token of next page

# Retrieve all the rest of the pages

while nextPageToken:
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId='+CHANNEL_ID+'&maxResults=50&type=video&key='+API_KEY+"&pageToken="+nextPageToken
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    videos_next_page = json.load(response)
    nextPageToken = videos_next_page.get("nextPageToken")


# loops through results and appends it to videoMetadata list 

# loop for the first page
for video in videos['items']:
    if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
        videoMetadata.append(video['id']['videoId'])

# loop for the next page       
for video in videos_next_page['items']:
    if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
```

It works ok, but maybe there is a better solution, how I can store results from multiple JSON responses in a list?

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works ok,

Actually, it doesn't, unless you only have one single "next page" - this:

```
while nextPageToken:
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId='+CHANNEL_ID+'&maxResults=50&type=video&key='+API_KEY+"&pageToken="+nextPageToken
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    videos_next_page = json.load(response)
    nextPageToken = videos_next_page.get("nextPageToken")
```

will overwrite `videos_next_page`  on each iteration, so you only get the last page.

> how I can store results from multiple JSON responses in a list

Once unserialized, "results from JSON responses" are plain ordinary python objects (usually `dict`s). And you append them to a list the same way you'd do for anything else.

Here's an possible rewrite that properly deals with this issue (and makes better use of memory too) - warning: untested code, so I can't garantee there's no typo or whatever, but at least you get the idea.

```
def load_page(page_token=None):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={}&maxResults=50&type=video&key={}".format(CHANNEL_ID, API_KEY)
    if page_token:
        url += ("&pageToken={}".format(page_token))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url) #makes the call to YouTube
    return json.load(response)

def collect_videos_meta(page):
    return [video['id']['videoId'] for video in page['items'] if video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video']

def main():
    videoMetadata = []
    nextPageToken = None # default initial value for the first page

    # using `while True` and `break` avoids having to repeat the same
    # code twice (once before the loop and once within the loop).
    # This is a very common pattern in Python, you just have to make
    # sure you will break out of the loop at some point...

    while True:
        page = load_page(nextPageToken)
        videoMetadata.extend(collect_videos_meta(page))
        nextPageToken = page.get("nextPageToken")
        if not nextPageToken:
            break

    # now do what you want with those data...
    print(videoMetadata)


if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like it should work. I will try it definitely tomorrow because already reached the limits per day.

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva a good way to avoid eating all your quota while in the dev phase is to store existing data locally and replace `load_page` with a mock that will serve those local data instead. You'll STILL need to test against the real API to validate your work, but at least in the meantime you can still work on those local data. You may want to have a look at VCRpy which automates much of the work: https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy